# How to get the h:selectManyListbox selected values from within a JSF converter?

Tags: jsf, converters, selectmanylistbox

I'm trying to populate a **h:selectManyListbox** with a **list of objects**, using a **converter**. I can easily convert each object to string in the *getAsString(...)* method, but I don't seem to find a clean solution to retrieve the same objects corresponding to the selected items from within the *getAsObject(...)* method inside the converter.

I tried using the faces context's requestMap/sessionMap, it works but I'm not sure that is the best approach for this.

I know I could use a map or perform some conversion straight into the managed bean, but my question is about using the converter only.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using SessionMap seems like good idea to me. The size of your map cannot be that large, so it wont impact performance or memory usage. But that is just my opinion

Comment: @Harry Pham: Thanks for your reply. The sessionMap works fine, but I'm not sure that is the right place where to store this kind of information. Anyway, if there's nothing else I can do, I will have to stick with that approach. Thanks again!

Comment: I actually never did it, but it I think it will be fine. Information store in SessionMap will be stored in Session. I cant imagine your selectManyListBox can be that big. So it will definitely be ok.